# python extracting photos from instagram post

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been trying to extract a photo from an Instagram post but to no avail.
example post: https://www.instagram.com/p/ChIj3ukOtOQ/

By inspecting elements in chrome I can see that the photo can be extracted using BeautifulSoup (the image URL is embedded in ). However, when I use a get request on the URL, it returns a response that does not contain the image URL.
this is what I have tried

```
import requests as rq
response = rq.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/CiNiO8oDcrl/")
print(response.text)
```

i'm suspecting this is because requests does not execute javascript?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Some sites have anti-bot protection to specifically stop stuff like this. I'm not sure if instagram has anti-bot measures, but this might be the reason. If this is the case, then try looking at something like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Comment: @MichaelM. I tried selenium and I get the same exact response

Comment: You might have to use their API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Comment: redirects to an accounts login paage. try incognito browser to see this in action. so no, and you will likely need to use api.